# Docusign template roles have an issue with signing order

Tags: docusignapi

This is with the Rest Api. My template has 2 signer roles, first one in the order is Customer and the second one is Spouse. If I use the template with both roles being used, the people getting the documents get the signing tabs and initials in the correct places. If I just send to the Spouse and keep the signing order as 1, the user gets the document, but now the tabs and initials are no longer there. It's the same document in both cases, but it appears to work only when both roles are being used. If I just send to the Spouse, but set the signing order to 2, then it works fine. So I guess if you are skipping signers in the signer order, make sure to set the signing order to what is being used in the template. Is this the expected behavior?

Comment: I'm curious if you have the routing orders for each role saved within the template itself?  You can verify by downloading the template and inspecting how those two roles are setup.

Comment: The signing order is set to 1 for Customer and 2 for Spouse. The checkbox for Set Signing Order is checked.

Comment: Ergin - if you want I could send you the json for that template.

Comment: No that's ok, but I think that's why the tabs are not getting assigned to the recipient.  What if you un-check the "set signing order" option in the template UI, which in turn removes the routing order for each recipient, then set the routing order through your API requests instead?  Do you get the same results?

Comment: I did try that and I still have a problem with what would be the second recipient.

Comment: @KathyLori - I'm having the same problem. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @EnterTheCode - I can't remember exactly how I addressed this. Sorry.

Comment: is this still an issue?

Comment: No this was addressed awhile back.